# Creating component of UICollectionView/UICollectionViewController by using Xib and Implement it in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to develop a component of UICollectionView or UICollectionViewController which I can use multiple time in my current project and also can be used anywhere by simply copy-pasting whole folder.

Requirements:
- Create an Xib of either UICollectionView or UICollectionViewController (which one is easier).
- Embed that CollectionView xib in my UIViewController, In my that UIViewController there are some graphs and also some pics that I've to show(collection view is for that).
- Basically I want to send a JSON file and some parameter if needed to that component and make the collection view running within that View controller.

I'm facing a lot of problems embedding both of UICollectionView and UICollectionViewController so what should be the best way and proper approach to do it?

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried so far so we could find out what is going wrong ?

Comment: I've tried to develop UICollectionViewController in Xib but I found it very hard to implement inside another View controller's UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **container view** to embed a view controller inside another view controller.

This is from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html):

> Container view controllers are a way to combine the content from
>   multiple view controllers into a single user interface

Comment: I've tried this solution but this is good if you're using Storyboard but I need to use Xib and If you delete embedded view controller it will basically referred as UIView and again I come to the same problem I was facing earlier.